# Any way to compare two workflows?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

In SharePoint Designer, in the list of "List Workflows", I have two workflows with the same name. They have two different modified dates and they're pretty complex, so eyeballing them for the differences isn't the easiest.

The workflow was created as a SP 2010 workflow and not a 2013 (don't know why - I didn't create it). Is there any way to export them to a readable format so I can compare them using something like Beyond Compare? I found [this article](http://netwovenblogs.com/2013/12/10/export-sharepoint-designer-2013-workflow-xaml/) but the "Save as Template" option is disabled. (I'm assuming the article doesn't apply as this was created as a 2010 workflow.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Designer, if you go to All Files, then Workflows, then click on the workflow name, it should make the xoml and xml files available which should work for your needs.